# change html span inner text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change a value of a span I am tried to do it like that:

```
$('#tList span.k-input').textContent = "(" + list.length + ") " + $('#tList span.k-input').html();
```

or

```
 $('#tList span.k-input').html() = "(" + list.length + ") " + $('#tList span.k-input').html();
```

if I hove over `$('#tList span.k-input').html()` it shows me the right value but nothing happens in the html.

Comment: pass the text inside html method. eg.  $('#tList span.k-input').html("(" + list.length + ") " + $('#tList span.k-input').html());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
var html = "(" + list.length + ") " + $('#tList span.k-input').html();
$('#tList span.k-input').html(html)
```

[<kbd>Read more</kbd>](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 0):

.html() is used to get contents of an element. To set inner content you can use the same function and pass the value as a parameter.

You can visit below url for reference
http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2